# Zeromq in-process communication - how to send a reference-message?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I'm interested in only in-process communication. How to avoid serializing messages and send them just by reference?

**UPD**

Another side of this question: how to convert C# reference to byte[] and byte[] to C# reference?

Comment: For the update, take a look at [Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A message queuing system is designed for inter-process communication. For communication within an application there are several options.
For a class Producer-Consumer problem, take a look at the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class.

Here's [an overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx).